# Secure WebSocket WSS (Self Signed Certificate) doesn't work on iOS Safari

Tags: ios, ssl, websocket, mobile-safari, mqtt

iOS doesn't allow to connect to WSS (Secure Websocket) when using a self signed certifcate.

Adding the certificate manually into iOS can be one of the solution. But not every client using the iOS will do it manually.

Cannot use unsecured WS as the project requirement is secured WSS and also cannot create a certificate from letsencrypt etc because we are using local domains which exist only within the intranet like test.local

Need a solution to allow WSS automatically work on iOS. Any bridge mechanism will also work on the server side if required.

Comment: The type of cers required by apple iOS 13 have changed. See: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210176

Answer (score -1):

Simple solution, don't use a self signed certificate for any real deployment.

Solutions like Lets Encrypt make getting hold of real certificates free and simple to automate.

Edit (to cover the new details)

If this a corporate deployment then have the admin include the CA certificate in the iOS policy.

If this is for consumers then it is just not possible, nobody will issue you a certificate for a `.local` address signed by a recognised CA. If it is for consumers then the only access to the device will be from their local network so why is there a hard requirement for wss?

Edit:

To be clear, this is also going to fail on pretty much any OS/browser, getting consumers to install CA certs is unlikely to happen (and they need to know to do it upfront).

A native app can pick it's own CA certs, but a browser can not.

You will also not get a recognised CA to sign a certificate for a `.local` hostname.

Comment: Using unsecured WS is obviously an option and I would have done that if the requirement was not for WSS. Lets Encrypt is also not a solution for me because we are using custom local domain like test.local which exist only in the intranet. It's like Fritzbox

Comment: Those details should have been in the original question. If this is internal only then have your administrator include the CA certificate in the corporate iOS profile.

Comment: Updated the question. Corporate iOS profile is also not a solution because the app will be used within multiple organizations and we cannot ask everyone to include the CA certificate for their corporate iOS profiles

Comment: Then it is just not possible